# ReferenceError:Can't find variable:weatherCondition

Tags: react-native, expo, weather-api, openweathermap

I am developing a Weather App which takes temperature and weatherCondition for json file of WeatherAPI. I get the error "ReferenceError:Can't find variable:weatherCondition".And if I take only temperature variable I get the same error "ReferenceError:Can't find variable:temperature"
You can find the tutorial here: https://blog.expo.io/building-a-minimalist-weather-app-with-react-native-and-expo-fe7066e02c09?gi=908ae5fd913d

This is the App.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Animated } from 'react-native';
import {API_KEY} from "./utils/WeatherAPIKey";
import Weather from './components/Weather';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading:false,
      temperature: 0,
      weatherCondition: null,
      error: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        this.fetchWeather(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      },
      error => {
        this.setState({
          error: 'Error Getting Weather Condtions'
        });
      }
    );
  }

  fetchWeather(lat = 25, lon = 25) {
    fetch(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&APPID=${API_KEY}&units=metric`
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        //console.log(json);
        this.setState({
          temperature:json.main.temp,
          weatherCondition:json.weather[0].main,
          isLoading:false
        })
      });
  }
  render() {
    const { isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {isLoading ? 
        (
          <Text>Fetching the weather</Text>
        ) : (
          <Weather weather={weatherCondition} temperature={temperature}/>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});


This is my Weather.js code

import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const Weather = ({temperature,weatherCondition}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.weatherContainer}>
      <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons size={48} name="weather-sunny" color={'#fff'} />
        <Text style={styles.tempText}>{temperature}˚</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.bodyContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>weatherCondition</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>It hurts my eyes!</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you also add the JSON response you're getting in your question?

Comment: here is the json link... http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=25&lon=25&APPID=a934bb6a3b87e7ac54ed10969b14d80b&units=metric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

There has been some changes but hope this will give you an Idea. This works for me and it should work for you as well. In the comments of this answer you attached an image with variable not found error. That is because you are not passing the states to the props right. Please follow this.

**App.js File**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Animated } from 'react-native';
import Weather from './Weather';


export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading:true,
            temperature: 0,
            weatherCondition: null,
            error: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        //     position => {
        //         this.fetchWeather(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        //     },
        //     error => {
        //         this.setState({
        //             error: 'Error Getting Weather Condtions'
        //         });
        //     }
        // );
        this.fetchWeather();
    }


    fetchWeather() {

        fetch(
            `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=25&lon=25&APPID=a934bb6a3b87e7ac54ed10969b14d80b&units=metric`
        )
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {
                //console.log(json);
                this.setState({
                    temperature:json.main.temp,
                    weatherCondition:json.weather[0].main,
                    isLoading:false
                })
            });
    }


    render() {
        const { isLoading, temperature } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {isLoading ?

                        <Text>Fetching the weather</Text>
                     :
                        <Weather temperature={temperature}/>
                    }
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

And Finally, here is the Weather.js File

**Weather.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class Weather extends React.Component{


    render(){

            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>{this.props.temperature}</Text>
                </View>
            );
   }

}
```

The reason why you are getting undefined is because of your weather.js file. I am not sure how it looks like as you have posted a very minimal example but mine should help you better understand how props works and how to pass it. Basically the `this.props.temparature` should be inside the weather.js thus making it an accessible prop to use. You can follow the same principle to make a weatherCondition prop as well.

As I do not know how your actual files are laid out, this was a minimal example. Hope this fixes the issue. It works for me. :)

Comment: I did as you said but its just showing the "fetching the weather" text....Nothing further

Comment: Hi. Are you sure your `fetch` is working? Can you try and `console.log(this.state.temperature)` and see if you are getting any value other than default 0. And if your fetch works fine, the isLoading should be set to false and it should do a re-render of the weather condition. Let me know

Comment: No i'm not getting any value other than 0...And the fetch function is working fine but the problem is in componentDidMount() I guess

Comment: Please check the updated Answer. Mine works on a test bench. Here: https://ibb.co/YhhzvhD

Comment: Set `weatherCondition` to `this.state.weatherCondition` and same for `temperature`. `this.state.temperature` and check. This is temporary. I will have the code updated if this works. Basically this line: `<Weather weather={weatherCondition} temperature={temperature}/>` change to: `<Weather weather={this.state.weatherCondition} temperature={this.state.temperature}/>`

Comment: ok... here's one more error message if it helps  https://ibb.co/8DqRXkb

Comment: Can I see your full Weather.js file? Or maybe upload it to git or somewhere so I can see your full project

Comment: Ok the final answer is updated. Please follow it accordingly. It is the minimal version which will help you understand and take off from there

Comment: No problem. If you have further questions, don’t hesitate to ask. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
render() {
    const { isLoading, temperature } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {isLoading ? 
        (
          <Text>Fetching the weather</Text>
        ) : (
          <Weather weather={weatherCondition} temperature={temperature}/>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: what your line does is it give the temperature value as the initial value...Not the vale we want from the json file..the temperature value shows 0 which is the default value